# Export cached webpage in Safari

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I have a webpage cached in Safari in iOS. The website isn't available anymore. Is there an option to export the website somehow? I don't have AirPrint ...

Answer (score 1):

I searched for AirPrint and because I have a Netgear router I used [Netgear genie](http://www.bandwidthblog.com/2012/05/10/want-to-print-from-your-iphoneipad-but-dont-have-an-airprint-printer/). Work wonderful. Can't save the page but I printed it.